# Channel Field Additional Options not Showing in 2.7

Tags: fields, 2.7.0

I have upgraded from 2.5.5 to 2.7. There is a problem that I don’t seem to understand.

When I tried picking any fieldtype for any field, before upgrading, normally JS would show more options at the bottom. This has been the standard behavior ever since I have used EE.

In this case, nothing shows. I looked at my firebug console and I saw this error

```
TypeError: d.ee_focus is not a function
...ocus(b.find("ul>li>a").eq(0)))},onEscape:function(a){a=c(a.target).parent();EE.n...
```

I looked at what file caused this and it was

```
admin.php?S=d3d3f2b7c7030e79c48804e28d9b425b&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,sortable,dialog&plugin=ee_interact.event,ee_notice,ee_txtarea,tablesorter,ee_toggle_all,ee_navigation&file=json2,underscore,cp/global_start&v=1355999354
```

I disabled Javascript and sure enough, it showed additional options, although in a very messy way.

How do you solve this Javascript problem?

Comment: According to the 2.7 changlog 'ee_focus' jQuery plugin has been removed. Something is calling it - perhaps you need to make sure all 2.5.5 files were overwritten. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html

Comment: Ok, you are correct. The themes folder just wasn't updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are having issues with JS interactions in the control panel not working correctly after an EE upgrade, the first thing to try is to reupload your control panel theme folder.

Comment: The problem really was that my themes folder somehow was retained on upgrade. So the JS was calling something that does not work for me anymore.

Comment: Sounds like we're saying the same thing...

Comment: Yup. I just discovered and applied the solution before you posted. I will mark your response as the answer regardless.